# How do I customize funiture with Cyrus?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Apparently you can use Cyrus to customize furniture (like couches and tvs). But when I bring things to him he says there's nothing of interest that I have on my person! How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

Cyrus can only customize certain pieces of furniture, so you must not have anything that is eligible for customization in your inventory. See the [furniture customization](https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/Furniture_Customization#New_Leaf) list to figure out if you have any eligible items.  The list is too long to post here.